# How does TMNT relate to other series from the Turtles franchise?

Tags: canon, teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles

The 2007 Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles movie has tenuous connections to the other movies (April & Casey are known and have a relationship, Shredder is defeated, Splinter's ear is cut).

Is it in the continuity of the movies, only, or does it have ties to other series?  Specifically, is it related at all to the newer TMNT TV show?  I know there's no connection between the three TV series (the 80s-90s series, The Next Mutation, and the 2000's series) and wondered if the movie was different.

Comment: They also have shredder's helmet and the time travel lantern in their home in TMNT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I seem to recall, the 2007 TMNT is something of a (very) loose sequel to the live action movies of the 90's. IMDB seems to [confirm this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0453556/faq#.2.1.3). Personally, I tend to think of it as residing its own continuity.